# Referenced (variable) data vs inline - Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, variables, memory, allocation

I couldn't find another question similar to this except this one:
[Storing Data in a Variable vs Inline Arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061234/storing-data-in-a-variable-vs-inline-arithmetic)

However that question was specific to Java, hence the micro memory management is really left to the JVM. My question relates to server-side JavaScript (ala NodeJs), and certain front-end frameworks like Ionic Framework.

Suppose we have some data and a function to utilize them.

```
var x;
var y;
var z;

var postRequest = function (x, y, z) {
    // some logic.
}
```

Data x, y, z need to be parsed and audited before passing into postRequest.

Is there any performance-memory-related advantage in just parsing the data inline as the parameter? As such (pay no mind to the arithmetic) :

```
postRequest( (x % y) / (z * (y % z)) );
```

vs this

```
var x1 = (x % y);
var y1 = (y % z);
var y2 = z * y1;
var x2 = x1 / y2;
postRequest(x2);
```

The latter is definitely easier to maintain and clean up later if needed. But do we sacrifice anything memory wise? I'm talking on a mass server scale, in a hypothetical situation where the function is run in the requests of thousands of users. Can we save anything performance wise running inline rather than creating references?

Comment: It's not a performance issue you'll see, but if you pass in those variables as a formula, you do not have the 3 chunks of memory stored for caching those values. You simply have the calcuated function parameter, which is used for whatever. So it's minuscule.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: If the function is compiled optimised, the 4 variables will probably never meet memory at all but stay in registers, just like in the inline version.

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean stay in registers? Doesn't it take time for the system to create memory for the 4 variables versus the 1 parameter?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'm saying the [compiler can completely optimise away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) any variables, no memory access should be needed. Like the linked Java answer says: Let's leave the microoptimisations to the JIT.